# Getting Data from Database Imports not working

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin

I am trying to set up a script that will run every half house or so to sort jobs out into priority's.

```
#from jobs.models import Jobs
#from django.db import models
#from jobs.states import RepairStates
# Get jobs
# Get models
# Get states

Job_set = Jobs.objects.filter(status="invoiced")
for jobs in Job_set:
    print(jobs.status)

print("Hello")

# Loop through all jobs that do not have a status of "invoiced"
# Calculate how many days until Due date / How many days past due date
# Check what state the job is in and add or take away points depending on state
# return points

# Quote Accepted = - 2
# Assigned engineer = -1
# request components = 0
# order fulfilled = 1
# test + 2
# Completed + 3
# for dispatch + 4
# COMPLETED + 100

#Do this every half hour, hour.
```

I have fallen at the first hurdle i cant seem to import the table data i need i have tried many times using different locations but it doesn't seem to work.

My directory is something like this

```
 twm--
      other files(not important)
      twm--
           accounts
           api
           component
           customer
           engineering
           goods
           jobs 
           personal 
         so on....
```

Now the model is in the jobs.models but i have tried that,

```
from jobs.models import Jobs
```

but it spits out an error telling me

```
     C:\Users\Staff\Documents\tsl\twm\twm>python priorityalgorithm.py
  Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "priorityalgorithm.py", line 1, in <module>
    from jobs.models import Jobs
  File "C:\Users\Staff\Documents\tsl\twm\twm\jobs\models.py", line 4, in     <module>
    from django.db import models
   File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from django.db.models.query import Q, QuerySet, Prefetch  # NOQA
   File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 16, in <module>
     from django.db.models import sql
   File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
     from django.db.models.sql.subqueries import *  # NOQA
   file "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\subqueries.py", line 9, in <module>
    from django.db.models.sql.query import Query
   File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py", line 17, in <module>
     from django.db.models.aggregates import Count
   File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\aggregates.py", line 5, in <module>
     from django.db.models.expressions import Func, Star
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\expressions.py", line 7, in <module>
    from django.db.models import fields
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py", line 19, in <module>
    from django import forms
   File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\forms\__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from django.forms.fields import *  # NOQA
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\forms\fields.py", line 21, in <module>
    from django.forms.utils import from_current_timezone, to_current_timezone
   File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\forms\utils.py", line 12, in <module>
    from django.utils.html import escape, format_html, format_html_join, html_safe
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\utils\html.py", line 13, in <module>
    from django.utils.http import RFC3986_GENDELIMS, RFC3986_SUBDELIMS
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\utils\http.py", line 10, in <module>
    from email.utils import formatdate
  File "C:\Users\Staff\Documents\tsl\twm\twm\email.py", line 1, in <module>
    from django.core.mail import EmailMultiAlternatives
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\core\mail\__init__.py", line 14, in <module>
    from django.core.mail.message import (
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\core\mail\message.py", line 8, in <module>
from email import (
ImportError: cannot import name 'charset'
```

Does anyone have any idea why this is happening?

Edit as requested jobs.models
EDIT - The file i am working on is located within the twm app next to the jobs module

```
from decimal import Decimal
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

from django.db import models
from django.conf import settings
from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
from django.core.exceptions import ObjectDoesNotExist

from statemachine.fields import FSM_StateField
from twm.component.models import Manufacturer
from twm.engineering.models import RefurbKit
from twm.workitem.models import WorkItem, WorkItemNote, WorkItemEmail
from twm.jobs.states import RepairStates
from twm.procurement.models import PurchaseOrderLine
from twm.engineering.models import ComponentLine
from twm.customer.models import ContactEmail

class Job(WorkItem):
    REFERENCE_START = 30000
    SLA_CHOICES = (('Standard', 'Standard'), ('Next day', 'Next day'),)
    SLA = models.CharField(max_length=20,
                           default='Standard', choices=SLA_CHOICES)
    part = models.ForeignKey("jobs.Part", null=True, blank=True)
    serial_no = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    status = FSM_StateField(machine=RepairStates, default_choices_all=True)
    quote_expiry = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    warranty = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    PriorityPoints = models.IntegerField(default=0, null=False)
    #    contact_emails = models.ManyToManyField('customer.ContactEmail')

    ident = "Repairs"

    def __unicode__(self):
        return "%s - %s" % (self.ref_number, self.customer)

    def add_note(self, user, note):
        return JobNote(user=user, note=note, item=self)

    def add_email(self, emails, subject, message, mime_type="text/html"):
        return JobEmail(item=self,
                        sent_to=emails,
                        subject=subject,
                        note=message,
                        upload_MIME=mime_type)

    def add_customer_as_contact(self):
        if self.customer and self.customer.addresses.count() > 0:
            address = self.customer.addresses.all()[0]
            contact, created = ContactEmail.objects.get_or_create(customer=self.customer,
                                                                  email=address.email,
                                                                  defaults={'name': address.contact_name})
            self.contact_emails.add(contact)

    def set_due_date(self):
        if self.status.state.name == "goods_arrived":
            deadlines = (1, 4)
        else:
            deadlines = (1, 6)

        if self.SLA == 'Next day':
            due_date = datetime.now() + timedelta(days=deadlines[0])
        else:
            due_date = datetime.now() + timedelta(days=deadlines[1])

            #can't be due on a weekend! (5=Saturday, 6=Sunday)
            add_days = 7 - due_date.weekday()
            if add_days < 3:
                due_date += timedelta(days=add_days)

        self.due_date = due_date

    def set_quote_expiry(self):
        self.quote_expiry = datetime.now() + timedelta(days=30)

    def get_notes(self):
        return self.notes.all()

    def get_open_quote(self):
        quotes = self.quote.filter(models.Q(accepted__isnull=True) |
                                   models.Q(accepted__gt=-1)).order_by('-date')
        if quotes:
            return quotes[0]

    def get_accepted_quote(self):
        quotes = self.quote.filter(accepted__gt=0).order_by('-date')
        if quotes:
            return quotes[0]

    def get_qa_state(self):
        last_qa_state = self.state_history.filter(from_state='production_qa')
        if last_qa_state:
            return last_qa_state[0]

    def update_value(self, save=True):
        value = Decimal(0)
        quotes = self.quote.filter(accepted__gt=0).order_by('-date')
        if quotes.count() == 0:
            quotes = self.quote.all().order_by('-date')
            if quotes.count() > 0:
                quote = quotes[0]
                value += quote.new_price or 0
                value += quote.used_price or 0
                value += quote.repair_price or 0
                value += quote.exchange_price or 0
                value += quote.other_price or 0
                value += quote.inbound_shipping_cost or 0
                value += quote.outbound_shipping_cost or 0
        else:
            for quote in quotes:
                ttl = quote.get_total()
                if ttl:
                    value += ttl
        self.value = value

        if save:
            self.save(None)

    def update_cost(self, save=True):
        po_lines = PurchaseOrderLine.objects.filter(
            component_line_id__in=self.components_list.all().values_list('id', flat=True),
            component_line_content_type=ContentType.objects.get_for_model(ComponentLine))

        price = 0

        for line in po_lines:
            if line.discount == 0:
                if line.get_supplier_discount() > 0:
                    line.discount = line.get_supplier_discount()
                    line.save()

            price += line.get_line_price()

        self.cost = price

        if save:
            self.save(None)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.update_value(save=False)
        self.update_cost(save=False)
        super(Job, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        if self.id:
            if self.status.state:
                return reverse(self.status.state.name, args=[self.id])
            else:
                return reverse('repair_created', args=[self.id])
        else:
            return reverse('repair_added')

    def is_order_filled(self):
        po_line_type = ContentType.objects.get_for_model(ComponentLine)
        for line in self.components_list.all():
            try:
                po_line = PurchaseOrderLine.objects.get(
                    component_line_content_type=po_line_type,
                    component_line_id=line.id,
                    purpose="repair")
            except PurchaseOrderLine.DoesNotExist:
                continue

            if not po_line.delivered:
                return False

        return True

    def split(self):
        new_repair = super(Job, self).split()
        # blank bits we don't need
        new_repair.due_date = None
        new_repair.order_number = None
        new_repair.tracking_details = None
        new_repair.tracking_link = None
        #copy the bits we do
        new_repair.part = self.part
        new_repair.SLA = self.SLA
        new_repair.serial_no = self.serial_no
        return new_repair


class JobNote(WorkItemNote):
    item = models.ForeignKey('jobs.Job', related_name='notes')
    upload = models.FileField(upload_to='job_files', null=True, blank=True)


class JobEmail(WorkItemEmail):
    item = models.ForeignKey('jobs.Job', related_name='email_notes')

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('li-view-email', kwargs={'model': 'job', 'pk': self.id})

    def get_raw_url(self):
        return reverse('li-raw-email', kwargs={'model': 'job', 'pk': self.id})
```

Comment: post your job.models

Comment: Looks like your problem somewhere else. Add full stacktrace

Comment: @itzmeontv Put it up :)

Comment: @SardorbekImomaliev Updates to put the rest of the traceback on

Comment: Looks like you are trying to use django parts outside of django environment. You need to write this as management command https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/custom-management-commands/

Comment: @SardorbekImomaliev  i just realised i'm not running the script in the VM but on the windows cmd. that could be the cause. right? ill try to run it on the vm now

Comment: @SardorbekImomaliev running it in the VM didn't work, but the piece you have sent me looks very promising, thank you for taking the time to help. It looks like exactly what i want. Thank you!

Comment: You have a local file called "email.py" which is shadowing the standard library module. Rename it.

Comment: @DanielRoseman Just did a search through 4800 paths there was no file called email.py

Answer (score 0):

Seems you have an custom app `email`. Try

```
>>>import email
>>>print email.__file__
```

Check from where email is importing from.